# Lemmatisation of web scraped data

Tags: python, nlp, text-parsing, stemming, lemmatization

Let's suppose that I have a text document such as the following:

```
document = '<p> I am a sentence. I am another sentence <p> I am a third sentence.'
```

( or a more complex text example:

```
document = '<p>Forde Education are looking to recruit a Teacher of Geography for an immediate start in a Doncaster Secondary school.</p> <p>The school has a thriving and welcoming environment with very high expectations of students both in progress and behaviour.&nbsp; This position will be working&nbsp;until Easter with a&nbsp;<em><strong>likely extension until July 2011.</strong></em></p> <p>The successful candidates will need to demonstrate good practical subject knowledge  but also possess the knowledge and experience to teach to GCSE level with the possibility of teaching to A’Level to smaller groups of students.</p> <p>All our candidate will be required to hold a relevant teaching qualifications with QTS  successful applicants will be required to provide recent relevant references and undergo a Enhanced CRB check.</p> <p>To apply for this post or to gain information regarding similar roles please either submit your CV in application or Call Debbie Slater for more information.&nbsp;</p>'
```

)

I am applying a series of pre-processing NLP techniques to get a "cleaner" version of this document by also taking the stem word for each of its words.

I am using the following code for this:

```
stemmer_1 = PorterStemmer()
stemmer_2 = LancasterStemmer()
stemmer_3 = SnowballStemmer(language='english')

# Remove all the special characters
document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', document)

# remove all single characters
document = re.sub(r'\b[a-zA-Z]\b', ' ', document)

# Substituting multiple spaces with single space
document = re.sub(r' +', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

# Converting to lowercase
document = document.lower()

# Tokenisation
document = document.split()

# Stemming
document = [stemmer_3.stem(word) for word in document]

# Join the words back to a single document
document = ' '.join(document)
```

This gives the following output for the text document above:

```
'am sent am anoth sent am third sent'
```

(and this output for the more complex example:

```
'ford educ are look to recruit teacher of geographi for an immedi start in doncast secondari school the school has thrive and welcom environ with veri high expect of student both in progress and behaviour nbsp this posit will be work nbsp until easter with nbsp em strong like extens until juli 2011 strong em the success candid will need to demonstr good practic subject knowledg but also possess the knowledg and experi to teach to gcse level with the possibl of teach to level to smaller group of student all our candid will be requir to hold relev teach qualif with qts success applic will be requir to provid recent relev refer and undergo enhanc crb check to appli for this post or to gain inform regard similar role pleas either submit your cv in applic or call debbi slater for more inform nbsp'
```

)

What I want to do now is to get an output like the one exactly above but after I have applied lemmatisation and not stemming.

However, unless I am missing something, this requires to split the original document into (sensible) sentences, apply POS tagging and then implement the lemmatisation.

But here things are a little bit complicated because the text data are coming from web scraping and hence you will encounter many HTML tags such as `<br>`, `<p>` etc.

My idea is that every time a sequence of words is ending with some common punctuation mark (fullstop, exclamation point etc) or with a HTML tag such as `<br>`, `<p>` etc then this should be considered as a separate sentence.

Thus for example the original document above:

```
document = '<p> I am a sentence. I am another sentence <p> I am a third sentence.'
```

Should be split in something like this:

```
['I am a sentence', 'I am another sentence', 'I am a third sentence']
```

and then I guess we will apply POS tagging at each sentence, split each sentence in words, apply lemmatization and `.join()` the words back to a single document as I am doing it with my code above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Removing HTML tags is the common part of text refining. You can use your own-writed rules like `text.replace('<p>', '.')` , but there is the better solution: [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/). This library can do all dirty HTML refining work for you, like:

```
>>> print h.handle("<p>Hello, <a href='http://earth.google.com/'>world</a>!")
Hello, world!
```

You can import this library in your Python code, or you can use it as a stand-alone program.

**Edit:** Here is the small chain example that splits your text to sentences:

```
>>> document = '<p> I am a sentence. I am another sentence <p> I am a third sentence.'
>>> text_without_html = html2text.html2text(document)
>>> refined_text = re.sub(r'\n+', '. ', text_without_html)
>>> sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(refined_text)
>>> sentences

['I am a sentence.', 'I am another sentence.', 'I am a third sentence..']
```

Comment: Thank you. To he honest, I am looking for a complete solution which also splits text documents into sentences; not only how to remove the HTML tags from a single sentence.

Comment: After you remove HTML tags, you can use NLTK's sent_tokenize to split your refined text into sentences: `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize` . Of course there is no magic functions that do everything, the refining process contains many small sequential functions :)

Comment: Haha ok I have the overall idea in mind; I just want the implementation.

Comment: Ok this looks better (upvote). However, keep in mind that I am not having only the <p> tag but also every other kind of HTML tag so I am not sure that this `refined_text = re.sub(r'\n+', '. ', text_without_html)` will work for every of them.

Comment: Also finally I want this: `['I am a sentence', 'I am another sentence', 'I am a third sentence']`. So the sentences without any punctuation marks.

Comment: I don't know what other type of HTML tags you have in your text. Just add another `re.sub` or `text.replace` line you need. Punctuation marks can be omitted with this: `text.strip('.,?!')` and any another symbol inside that line.

Comment: Ok even though I guess that there has to be a smarted way with `re` for the punctuation marks.